# how to covert callbacks to promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, promise, callback

i have next code

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
              if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
                res.send({link:payment.links[i].href});
              }
            }
        }
});
```

i neen to convert that to a promise:

```
const { links } = await paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json);
```

Comment: [here you are](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: Be careful that your code can't call `res.send()` multiple times

Comment: I know, it's an example of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const PaypalPromise = module.exports;

const Paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk').configure({
  mode: 'sandbox',
  client_id: 'your id',
  client_secret: 'your secret',
});

PaypalPromise .create = (pay) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Paypal.payment.create(pay, (error, payment) => {
    if (error) return reject(error);

    return resolve(payment);
  });
});
```